# Invalid positive integer Stripe Payments error after payment page refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, credentials

Hey guys so basically that error is popping after i fill my payment information, I go thru the cart into the Payment page and after I write my info, it seems to go thru but ends up showing that error

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @cart = current_user.carts.where(status: 'pending').last
    @amount = @cart.deals.sum(&:final_cost)
  end

  def create
    @amount = (params[:final_cost].to_f*100).round
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      email: params[:stripeEmail],
      source: params[:stripeToken]
    )

    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      customer: customer.id,
      amount: @amount,
      description: 'Rails Stripe customer',
      currency: 'usd'
    )

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to new_charge_path
  end
end
```

Charges/new.html.erb

```
<h1 class="title">Charges#new</h1>
<%= form_tag charges_path do %>
  <article>
    <% if flash[:error].present? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <p><%= flash[:error] %></p>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <label class="amount">
      <span>Amount: $<%= @amount %></span>
    </label>
  </article>
  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
          data-description="<%= "#{Rails.env}-#{@cart.id}" %>"
          data-amount="<%= @amount*100 %>"
          data-locale="auto">
  </script>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Usually this means you are passing an empty value or `0` to the `amount` field when creating a `Charge`. I'd double check the value you're expecting is in `@amount` when you're seeing this error.

Comment: @taintedzodiac hey man, yes, but the amount is actually going thru. thats why is weird. I inspect the page and the amount is actually (in this case) 360, which is right

Comment: I see you're displaying `@amount` but then calculating `@amount*100` so that's also worth making sure they are both integers if you're ever using them for Stripe values.

Comment: hey @taintedzodiac they are both decimal in the schema, however i converted them both .to_f. But is passing as nil